# How to yield in subscription call back of Google Pubsub on Flask Server for streaming

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to have a stream via a Flask endpoint, but events are sent within the callback of the subscriber to a topic (Google Cloud PubSub). See the code below:

```
def a_stream():
    topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
        project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
        topic="topic",  
    )
    subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{sub}'.format(
        project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
        sub="topic", 
    )
    def callback(message):
        print("print")
        yield "yield"
        message.ack()

    with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient() as subscriber:
        try:
            subscriber.create_subscription(
            name=subscription_name, topic=topic_name)
        except:
            #do nothing as topic exists
            pass
        future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback=callback)             
        future.result()

@orders_bp.route("/aStream", methods=['GET'])
def get_order_status():
    return Response(stream_with_context(a_stream()),
                          mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

If I run the code as is, nothing happens. If I remove the yield in the callback, then I can see the "print" in the console. It seems the issue is to do with the yielding, is there an easy way to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

The Python yield statement suspends execution and returns a value to the caller. In your case you are expecting the string "yield" but actually a generator is returned. No state is created in the function, such as a for or while loop (as in generators) or multiple yields, so when the function resumes, a generator containing a string "yield" is returned again. The line of code **message.ack()** will never execute.

Let's examine your code:

```
def callback(message):
    print("print")
    yield "yield"
    message.ack()
```

and translate it into an example:

```
class message:
        def ack():
                print('ACK')

def callback(message):
    print("print")
    yield "yield"
    message.ack()

val = callback(message)
print(type(val))

for i in val:
        print(i)
```

If we call **callback** and check its return type:

```
val = callback(message)
print(type(val))
```

The type(val) is <class 'generator'>

To get the returned value from the generator you must **iterate** the result:

```
for i in val:
        print(i)
```

You are using callback as a normal method and expecting a string to be returned.

```
val = callback(message)
```

The calling code is **not** calling the method as a generator. Therefore, no state is saved or restored within **callback** and the method starts over with each call.

For your use case, change your code to not use generators:

```
def callback(message):
    message.ack()
    return "yield"
```

Otherwise, you must modify **subscriber.subscribe()** to accept a generator instead of a function callback.